# Which display controller board to use for 13" MacBook Pro (mid-2012, unibody) display panel?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

My 13" MacBook Pro (mid-2012, unibody) doesn't work anymore and I decided to convert its display into an external monitor. I have taken apart display of my MacBook Pro from the original laptop but I can't order controller board from eBay/Amazon since I don't know which one will work for that screen. Can anybody help me with this? If somebody can tell me display panel number of the MacBook Pro from that year it would help me order board for mine.

Comment: That won't be enough, you will need a specific backlight driver as well.

Comment: Can you explain in brief what's the backlight driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can get the part you need via Louis Rossman's site ([mailin.repair](http://mailin.repair)) and probably schematics as well. Or st least pointers towards them.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cory for your comment. I explored mailin.repair and seems like LTN133AT09 is the correct display panel model number for 13" MacBook Pro (mid-2012, unibody). Thanks again. :)

Comment: @hellSigma you're welcome!  Glad you found the right part. I'd like to know the results once you've completed the repair.

Comment: Sure, once completed I'll reply back with the final result and some pictures of the working external monitor. :)

Answer (score -1):

If by "display panel number" you mean the Apple part # for a complete display unit for the 13" Unibody Mid 2012 MacBook Pro, then it's: **661-6594**. Just to be clear, this is the Apple part # for the following models:

- MacBook Pro 13.3" 2.5GHz Core i5 (A1278) - Mid 2012 (MD101LL/A)
- MacBook Pro 13.3" 2.9GHz Core i7 (A1278) - Mid 2012 (MD102LL/A)

Comment: I was talking about the display panel model number. I need that to find the correct controller for my display.